# Всплывающее окно при первом визите на сайт

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Сделали сайт Sex Shop. Теперь нужно, чтобы при входе на сайт первый раз выходило окно "Вам есть 18?" и кнопки "Да" или "Нет". Подскажите, где можно посмотреть готовые скрипты? Помню, был у Дмитрия Валлака, найти что-то не могу у него. Может, у кого валяется в закладках?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1: Отпраляй cookie при входе на сайт и проверяй их наличие при каждом просмотре страницы.
Вариант 2: Проверяй адрес, с которого перешли на страницу. Если совпадает с адресом твоего сайта, то не выводи окно, иначе - выводи.

Answer (score 0):

То, что показываем пользователю, это пример с моего сайта:

```
<span class="theme_changelog_show"><u>Показать zapraudu changelog</u></span><div class="changelog_panel">
        <a class="welcome-panel-close theme_changelog_close">Закрыть</a>
            <h3>Информация обо всех проводимых работах на сайте zapraudu.info</h3>
            <p><b>01.10.2014</b> - Убраны виджеты на главной в админ панели.</p>
            <p><b>01.10.2014</b> - Оптимизация загрузки скриптов админ панели.</p>
            <p><b>30.09.2014</b> - Оптимизирована загрузка css сайте.</p>
            <p><b>30.09.2014</b> - Для подготовки к редизайну оптимизирована страница парользователей, синижена нагрузка на сервер.</p>
            <p><b>29.09.2014</b> - По техническим причинам произведен откат базы за 26.09.2014</p>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
            <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {
                        if ($.cookie('hide_theme_changelog') == 'true') {
                            $( '.changelog_panel' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                            $( '.theme_changelog_show' ).css( 'display', 'inline' );
                        } else {
                            $( '.changelog_panel' ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                            $( '.theme_changelog_show' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                        }
                        $( '.theme_changelog_close' ).click( function() {
                            $( '.changelog_panel' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                            $( '.theme_changelog_show' ).css( 'display', 'inline' );
                            $.cookie( 'hide_theme_changelog', 'true', { expires: 32 } );
                        });
                        $( '.theme_changelog_show' ).click( function() {
                            $( '.changelog_panel' ).css( 'display', 'block' );
                            $( '.theme_changelog_show' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                            $.removeCookie( 'hide_theme_changelog' );
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Обязательно подключите библиотеку https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь http://editlw.ru/articles.php?article_id=357 описан вариант установки для cms php-fusion и ссылки на скачивание файлов javascript. Самое то что вам нужно. Cookie по умолчанию хранятся 30 дней но можно изменить. Файлы для установки разместите в нужных вам местах - как этого требует ваш cms движок.